# Highcharts - pie chart with html div at center

Tags: javascript, highcharts

**What I want** to create in Highcharts.js in React Native: 
[image: this is what I want to create]

I had 2 options :

1. Render a circle at the centre on donut chart using `chart.renderer.circle` and then add Image, Text, Shadow or zIndex.
   But I couldn't figure out how to add Image/Text/Shadow to the rendered Circle.
   Here is a [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshshamra1201/mchgn58p/) of this approach.
2. Place a div just above the highcharts div container and apply shadow, Image, Text there. 
   Here is a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mukeshshamra1201/znm5vb1d/) of this approach.
   The second approach pretty much worked, but there are many problems, like

   - **Tooltips hide under the overlapping div**
   - Width of the graph is larger than the mobile screen width.

Has anyone done this type of graph? Can you suggest me a better way to draw this graph?

> Most Imp thing for me is shadow effect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add an image:

```
// Build the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...
}, function(chart) {
    var textX = chart.plotLeft + (chart.series[0].center[0]);
    var textY = chart.plotTop + (chart.series[0].center[1]);

    chart.renderer.image(
        'https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png',
        textX - 15,
        textY - 15,
        30,
        30
    ).add();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zp7suewr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image

Comment: Thanks, @ppotaczek but I tried this approach earlier but could not figure out how to add shadow effect.

Comment: The main problem is that the image gets rendered behind the chart, and not above the chart. So even if I take an image with shadow and make it slightly bigger than the innerSize , the shadow gets cropped. [see demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mukeshshamra1201/a3te2ckx/)

Comment: And this is not responsive as well, after resizing the window, Image doesn't move, but the graph does.

Comment: Hi @mukesh.kumar, You can set `zIndex` and dynamically reposition the image in `render` event. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y7no2vcj/